# Android xamarin How record network stream video(udp multicast) in file?

Tags: android, video, xamarin, video-streaming

I have multicast UDP video stream and android box.

I wrote application on xamarin for android box
that plays this video stream.

Now, I want to write code for the application, that would record video stream to file on the android box and play video from the file when user will want. It will be "TimeShift" and PVR (Personal Video Recorder) function for my application.

I looked at a lot of examples, but there is showed only record video stream from the camera.

If anyone has example code for my case, please share with me.

I tried to use various elements to connect and write data (UdpClient, HttpClient, also UdpSocket from plugin rda.SocketsForPCL). Received an error of connection and error protocol type or protocol is not supported.
Is there a way to connect and save data from udp stream (video)?

```
string host;
string port;
IPAddress ip_multi = IPAddress.Parse(host);
IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ip_multi, Convert.ToInt32(port));
Socket clientSocket;
    try
          {
        clientSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
         int Length;
         Byte[] b = new Byte[Length];
         clientSocket.Connect(ipEndpoint);
         clientSocket.Receive(b);
         //clientSocket.BeginReceive(b, 0, Length, SocketFlags.Multicast, receiveCallback, clientSocket);
          clientSocket.Close();
          }
         catch (IOException ex)
          {
           Log.Debug("esception","error!"+ex.ToString());            
          }
```

Comment: please post what you have done yet so far

Comment: Please tell me what exactly you want to do? and please share your code snippet.